# vba error 424: Object required

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2010, vba, Win 7.
I am using an on change event to run some code to update some other sheets. Works fine in every instance except one.
Quick description of what I'm doing: copying column 2 (or 4) to column 2 (or 4) of every other sheet when said column (2 or 4) is changed, and performing some other operations. Other called macros work fine.
 If I try to delete or clear a range of cells containing the last cell (down) in column 2, then it gives the error 424. Any other operation (typing, copying, deleting) works fine, as long as the last cell still has stuff in it. To be clear, by last cell I mean the last cell  in the column (downwards) which contains  text. There are still others above it with text.
Apparently I can't post images yet, so I can't illustrate for you what's going on more clearly.

The code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If (Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 4) Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim I, WS_Index, WS_Count As Integer
WS_Index = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

'copy bbcodes and consolidations across sheets
For I = 1 To WS_Count
    If I <> WS_Index Then
         'Error is thrown on this line!
         ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WS_Index).Columns(Target.Column).Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(I).Columns(Target.Column)
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(I).Activate
    FillbyExample
Next I
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WS_Index).Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

I'm very new to this (since Monday!), and despite all I've learned and much searching I'm unable to determine what's going on. Any help would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: Just tested it and it works fine for me. Which line gives you the error?

Comment: In the middle, the one below the comment that says "error thrown on this line" (the one which does the copying). Thanks for helping, I've learned much from you the past couple of days :)

Comment: Can you upload your file to some file sharing site and share the link here. Like I said, I am not getting an error. BTW I am not sure what `FillbyExample` does in your code so I removed that before testing

Comment: Sure, I was doubtful you'd want to download a macro workbook but I'll send a link in a bit. FillByExample is just another macro, no worries about deleting it. edit: http://www5.zippyshare.com/v/89344411/file.html

Comment: No worries if you can't replicate the error, I don't know what's going on. Personally I've found the fastest approach with this sort of problem is to just do the same thing differently (especially in C++!!), could you suggest any code?

Comment: i'm just guessing that maybe the macro `FillbyExample` resets application.enableevents to true, wich souldn't be. Also, as i don't know what `fillbyexample` does, MAYBE the `End if` might be moved after fillbyexample...   Last thing, i don't think it is necessary to activate sheets(i)

Comment: also when copying, excel pastes multiple cells as as lines, so you might need a transpose somewhere with pastespecial, or do a loop (for each cell in sheets(i).columns(target.column)) ....

Comment: I think it may be you first comment (not the second though) - I'll check monday. Very good thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much less elegant, but in the end I simply settled on:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WS_Index).Columns("B").Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(I).Range("B1")
```

as I only really needed it for those two columnns.